# Sum function with join is giving sum multiplies number of times of entries in laravel ORM with mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, join

There are 2 tables `bills and payments`, and total sales are inserted into an order table and revenue is inserted into payment table. I wanted to show total sales and total cash collection of last 7 days but my query giving me result multiplies by the number of times a data of the same date in laravel.

table **bills**:
[image]

table **payments**:
[image]

I want to fetch the total amount of each day of the last seven days where `bills.created_date=payments.created_date`. my query works good but it gives me total sum multiply by entries of the particular day.

My query (Laravel):

```
public function salesAndRevenue(){
    $date = new Carbon\Carbon;

    $salesAndRevenue = 
        DB::table('bills')
        ->Join(
            'payments', 
            DB::raw('DATE(payments.created_at)'), 
            '=',
            DB::raw('DATE(bills.created_at)'))
        ->select(
            DB::raw('DATE(payments.created_at) as date'),
            DB::raw('sum(payments.amount) as total_revenue'),
            DB::raw('sum(bills.total_amount) as total_sales'))
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(payments.created_at)'))
        ->where(
            DB::raw('DATE(bills.created_at)'),
            '>',
            $date->subDays(7)->toDateTimeString())
        ->get()->toArray();    

        return $salesAndRevenue;
    }
```

My expected result:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#254 ▼
    +"date": "2019-03-11"
    +"total_revenue": 5.0
    +"total_sales": 5.0
  }
  1 => {#255 ▼
    +"date": "2019-03-12"
    +"total_revenue": 1500.0
    +"total_sales": 1500.0
  }
]
```

my output:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#254 ▼
    +"date": "2019-03-11"
    +"total_revenue": 5.0
    +"total_sales": 5.0
  }
  1 => {#255 ▼
    +"date": "2019-03-12"
    +"total_revenue": 4500.0
    +"total_sales": 4500.0
  }
]
```

But this code works perfectly without using join to fetch data from a single table.
like:

```
$sales = 
    DB::table('bills')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as date'), 
        DB::raw('sum(total_amount) as total_sales'))
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->where(
        DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'),
        '>',
        $date->subDays(7)->toDateTimeString())
    ->get()->toArray();
```

output:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => {#259 ▼
    +"date": "2019-03-11"
    +"total_sales": 5.0
  }
  1 => {#260 ▼
    +"date": "2019-03-12"
    +"total_sales": 1500.0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem comes from you `JOIN` condition:

```
DB::table('bills')
->Join(
    'payments', 
    DB::raw('DATE(payments.created_at)'), 
    '=', 
    DB::raw('DATE(bills.created_at)')
)
```

You are removing the time part of the dates, then joining: hence you end up with several matching `payments` for each `bill`.

From your sample data, it looks to me like column `payments.bill_id` is there for the purpose of joining:

```
DB::table('bills')
->Join(
    'payments', 
    DB::raw('payments.bill_id'), 
    '=', 
    DB::raw('bills.id')
)
```